# How to make two Get requests, the second one can only be made after the return of the first one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using [tvmaze's](https://www.tvmaze.com/api) API to make the list of series.

On the main screen, I need to list the name and image of the series and also the list with the episodes that this series contains.

For that I need to make two `GET` requests, the first to bring all the series and the second to bring the episodes that this series contains.

Can you tell me how to do the second GET only after the first one is finished?

I am developing the application in ReactJS and Redux. I put my project into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-thompson-f6hg4?file=/src/App.js)

**My Actions:**

```js
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://api.tvmaze.com";

export const getMoviesList = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "MOVIES_LIST_LOADING",
    });

    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/shows`);

    dispatch({
      type: "MOVIES_LIST_SUCCESS",
      payload: response,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: "MOVIES_LIST_FAIL",
    });
  }
};

export const getEpisodesList = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "EPISODES_LIST_LOADING",
    });

    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/shows/${id}/episodes`);

    dispatch({
      type: "EPISODES_LIST_SUCCESS",
      payload: response.data,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: "EPISODES_LIST_FAIL",
    });
  }
};
```

**My GET's**

The problem is to do the second GET (getEpisodesList), it is not working with this `if` that I implemented.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { getMoviesList, getEpisodesList } from "./store/actions/moviesAction";

import Routes from "./views/Routes";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const movieState = useSelector((state) => state.moviesListReducer);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getMoviesList());

    if (movieState.data.data) {
      movieState.data.data.map((ep) => dispatch(getEpisodesList(ep.id)));
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Routes />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try using `async-await`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the logic behind what you want to do

```
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const movieState = useSelector((state) => state.moviesListReducer);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // if movieState is idle or not loading
    if (condition) {
      dispatch(getMoviesList());
    }
  // Update the dependencies to include the idle/loading state
  }, [dispatch]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // if movieState is fulfilled
    if (condition) {
      movieState.data.data.forEach((ep) => {
        dispatch(getEpisodesList(ep.id));
      });
    }
  // Update the dependencies here to include the fulfilled state
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Routes />
    </>
  );
};
```

That's the basic logic for what you're trying to do. Your reducer code isn't described, that's why I've included comments.

But this approach may not be optimal as you may end up making too many requests depending on the amount of movies/shows.